# Expressing $U_{xy}$ via Multivariable chain rule

Tags: calculus

Let $r=y^2$, $s=xy$, $t=-x^2$,  and consider $u=f(r,s,t)$, where $f$ has continuous second order partial derivatives.

$$U_{xy}= Af_s(r,s,t)+ Brf_{rs}(r,s,t)+ Csf_{ss}(r,s,t)+ Dsf_{rt}(r,s,t)+ Etf_{st}(r,s,t)$$

Use the multivariable chain rule to find the values of A,B,C,D and E.

What i did

I drew the tree diagram to releate all the variables together.

to get

$$U_{xy}=U_rr_y+U_{s}s_x+U_{s}s_y+U_tt_x$$

From here i got

$$U_{xy}=2yU_r+yU_{s}+xU_{s}-2xU_t$$

However im stuck from here onwards.Could anyone explain. Thanks